# How to make setuptools clone git dependencies recursively?

Tags: python, git, setuptools

I want to let `setuptools` install `Phoenix` in my project and thus added

```
setup(
    ...
    dependency_links = [
        "git+https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix.git#egg=Phoenix"
    ],
    install_requires = ["Phoenix"],
    ...
)
```

to my `setup.py`, but `Phoenix`' `setuptools` setup depends on a recursive `git` clone. How to tell the `setuptools` setup of my project to do `git clone --recursive` for `Phoenix`?

Defining a `git` alias with `git config --global alias.clone 'clone --recursive'` doesn't change anything.

I'm using `setuptools` 18.2 with `python` 2.7 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer that could solve this! [This blog post](https://oak-tree.tech/blog/python-packaging-primer) explains it. It assumes though that you have access to the source code `Phoenix` in this case. Essentially, you have to apply the following addition to `Phoenix`'s `setup.py`. It doesn't help applying it to *your* `setup.py` sadly. In short:

```py
from setuptools.command.develop import develop
from setuptools.command.install import install
from setuptools.command.sdist import sdist

def gitcmd_update_submodules():
    ''' Check if the package is being deployed as a git repository. If so, recursively
        update all dependencies.

        @returns True if the package is a git repository and the modules were updated.
            False otherwise.
    '''
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(HERE, '.git')):
        check_call(['git', 'submodule', 'update', '--init', '--recursive'])
        return True

    return False


class GitCmdDevelop(develop):
    def run(self):
        gitcmd_update_submodules()
        develop.run(self)


class GitCmdInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        gitcmd_update_submodules()
        install.run(self)


class GitCmdSDist(sdist):
    def run(self):
        gitcmd_update_submodules()
        sdist.run(self)

setup(
    cmdclass={
        'develop': GitCmdDevelop, 
        'install': GitCmdInstall, 
        'sdist': GitCmdSDist,
    },
    ...
)
```