# How can I add dependency link to repo subdirectory in setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have following two repositories:
one classic with setup.py, and second which looks like:

`/repo
    /folder1
    /folder2
        /utils
        /setup.py`

and in setup.py in first repo I want install utils from second repo.
I tried following code:

```
install_requires=["repo"],
dependency_links=['git+ssh://git@bitbucket.aaaaaaa.aa:0000/project/repo@master#egg=repo&subdirectory=folder2']
```

but after python setup.py develop I have following error:

`unknown url type: git+ssh -- Some packages may not be found!`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get pip to work with git and github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737500/get-pip-to-work-with-git-and-github-repository)

Comment: can you try it with the `--process-dependency-links` option for pip?

Comment: also possible duplicate of [How to make setuptools clone git dependencies recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386794/how-to-make-setuptools-clone-git-dependencies-recursively)

Answer (score 4):

I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61930615).

janfreyberg answer does not work anymore because of a change in `pip`:
**since 19.0, `dependency_links` are now obsolete.**

Since `pip` 18.1, we can put these dependencies in `install_requires` using a syntax introduced by [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/).

Here is the solution in your case:

```
install_requires=[
    'repo @ git+ssh://git@bitbucket.aaaaaaa.aa:0000/project/repo@master#subdirectory=folder2'
]

setup(install_requires=install_requires)
```

Note that this requires using `pip install .` and doesn't work with `python setup.py install`.

If `folder2` itself has dependencies, everything will be retrieved recursively.

Answer (score 2):

I found this works for me:

```
depndendcy_links=["git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI#egg=pycocotools-2.0"]
```

So, specify the subdirectory and version as `#subdirectory=<sub_dir>#<packagename>-<version>`