# Installing dependency from a VCS repo subdirectory using setuptools

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I'm trying use setuptools to install a dependency from a VCS and inside a subdirectory.

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from setuptools import setup

required = [
    "package"
]
dependency_links = [
    "git+ssh://git@host/repo.git@tag#subdirectory=subdir#egg=package-version"
]

setup(install_requires=required, dependency_links=dependency_links)
```

Running `python3 setup.py install` in a virtualenv, I get the following error:

`Download error on git+ssh://git@host/repo.git@tag#subdirectory=subdir#egg=package-version: unknown url type: git+ssh -- Some packages may not be found!`

For the sake of debugging, I used the following public Github repo instead:

```
required = [
    "pycocotools"
]
dependency_links = [
    "git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI#egg=pycocotools-2.0"
]
```

This example was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53498195) as a solution to a similar question.
I got the same `unknown url type` error (the package is eventually retrieved through PyPI, not through the VCS URL !).

## What I've tried

```
git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI#egg=pycocotools-2.0
```

- `python3 setup.py install`: `unknown url type: git+https -- Some packages may not be found!`
- `pip3 install`: `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-lwpbj7yv/pycocotools-2.0/PythonAPI#egg=pycocotools-2.0': '/tmp/pip-install-lwpbj7yv/pycocotools-2.0/PythonAPI#egg=pycocotools-2.0'`

```
git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI&egg=pycocotools-2.0
```

- `python3 setup.py install`: `unknown url type: git+https -- Some packages may not be found!`
- `pip3 install`: OK, but `WARNING: Generating metadata for package pycocotools-2.0 produced metadata for project name pycocotools. Fix your #egg=pycocotools-2.0 fragments.`

```
git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI&egg=pycocotools
```

- `python3 setup.py install`: `unknown url type: git+https -- Some packages may not be found!`
- `pip3 install`: OK

I've also tried removing the `git+` for all these URLs, but it `cannot detect archive format`.

## Versions I'm using

- setuptools 46.4.0
- python 3.6.9
- pip 20.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dependency_links` were declared obsolete and finally [removed](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) in `pip` 19.0. The replacement for it is `install_requires` with special syntax (supported since `pip` 19.1):

```
install_requires=[
    'package_name @ git+https://gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID>'
]
```

See https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references

This requires `pip install` including `pip install .` and doesn't work with `python setup.py install`.

In your case:

```
install_requires=[
    "package @ git+ssh://git@host/repo.git@tag#subdirectory=subdir"
]

setup(install_requires=install_requires)
```

For example:

```
install_requires=[
    pycocotools @ git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI
]
```

Comment: Thanks !
Earlier I stumbled upon this `package @ url` syntax, but I did not try it with `pip install .`